# Unexpected output for Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I tried below code and I got this output.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set s = new HashSet();
    s.add("a");
    s.add("b");
    s.add("c");
    s.add("d");

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output :-[d, b, c, a]
But on a another pc I got [a, b, c, d].
What is the problem? Is it in the code or in the pc?

Comment: I guess the error is in your understanding.

Comment: A HashSet does not have predictable ordering.

Comment: Can you explain me?

Comment: what is the thing that deciding the output of hashmap?

Comment: @RavinduShashikaIlangamge When you print out the HashSet, the toString method gets invoked, which uses an Iterator to print out the contents.

Comment: If you wanted to keep insertion order, use a `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used `HashSet` and expected that the order will be constant.

[HashSet (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) says:

> in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.